# Object Oriented Naming Conventions 

Tags: php, oop, methods

What is the name of having code structured with methods attached to objects?

For example:

```
" ... ".trim
```

or

```
obj.method()
```

At first many would argue this is **Object oriented**, but `php` is Object Oriented(well partially), yet it syntax is completely different `trim("  ... ")`.

### TL;DR "Object Oriented" and "Everything is an Object" aren't valid answers unlesss......

People constantly suggest PHP is "Object Oriented" and libraries are "Object Oriented", yet PHP library's code is often structured with tons of static classes.

For example RedBean:

- R::dispense($bean)
- R::store($bean)
- R::trash($bean)

That doesn't follow the `obj.method` syntax, yet is supposedly Object Oriented.   Is PHP's object orientation misleading, or is there a better name for `obj.method()` coding style.

Comment: Closers please leave an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can do both. You can write object oriented code, and you can write procedural code.
Procedural code is much easier to understand and write, and most PHP programmers don't *really* understand OOP, so they write, what I call, procedural code disguised as OOP.
This includes things like static methods, and singletons.

Comment: I totally agree, except static and singleton. They have their places in OOP, but you are right that most people use them incorrectly.

Comment: What makes Procedural code easier?  It just appears to make really looooong func names and they pollute the global namespace.  Is it just out of habit?  Because I definitely find it confusing and long...

Comment: It's easier to understand conceptually.

Comment: @pinusnegra Has there just been poor education toward standards?  Why would people intentionally do incorrect OOP?

Comment: There has been no education. Most PHP programmers are self taught, usually designers who wanted to stop relying on programmers.

Comment: @Lime because they don't understand fully what is OOP, and they try to do procedural style programming in OOP. And the best tool for it is static classes/methods and 'god objects'

Answer (score 1):

Much of the core functions of PHP is C heritage, so don't get surprised if it doesn't follow OOP conventions.

The important thing is that calling methods on objects *does* follow OOP conventions.

Comment: Other then Ruby(and node.js) which Web Development languages are Object Oriented?  Because Python doesn't even appear to follow true OOP.  For example: `trim("  ...   ")`

Comment: Ruby is not really a Web Development language, anymore than Java and C# are.

Comment: In ruby you can even call methods on integers, but for me all of them are Object Oriented.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in PHP are not considered to be objects but scalar values. Therefore the syntax `"..."->trim()` cannot work unless the scalar string literal is converted to object first.

There is an open proposal for auto-boxing (auto-converting of a scalar value to object). This would allow the usual object oriented syntax. Auto-boxing, however does have a little performance penalty. See more here:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/autoboxing

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info, it doesn't exactly answer the naming question but its great to know.  In JavaScript Strings and Numbers are also considered to be scalar values(well primitive types) yet it does hold to the `obj.method()` OOP syntax.  I hope PHP chooses to switch their syntax, but that is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of RedBeanPHP I use static methods for the facade. This is more user friendly than purist OO code. You don't have to know about all the internals of RedBeanPHP in order to use it (there is also an OO way to use the lib). In my opinion RedBeanPHP is really object oriented; behind the facade it uses inheritance, interfaces, polymorphism and patterns like adapters, factories, observers.

Also, I believe OOP is more like a way of thinking than just a syntax thing. For instance you can just as well craft object oriented systems using structs and function pointers or like GTK does. OOP features in languages are just to facilitate. Also, because PHP is a dynamic language (in contrast to static typed) it does not have to rely on types, it can just scan objects for desired behaviours. In my opinion this is a good thing because it is more flexible and more maintainable the deep class hierarchies like in Java. I used to be an OO purist but I have recently embraced OOP-pragmatism; just use the best of both worlds.

Comment: Appreciate the response, yeah I often use a mix also